# Is it possible to define a child router with a different routing path?

Tags: aurelia

Per default, the routing table is defined by convention in Aurelia, because the path of the child route matches the path of the parent route.

```
/content/items -> components/item-list (<router-view>)
/content/items/:id -> components/item-details
```

I want to define a child route with a different path as it works in [angularjs ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)

```
/content/items -> components/item-list (<router-view>)
/items/:id -> components/item-details
```

Is there any way to implement that?